# How to select all the sum(column) for the same hour for unique ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the table I have where level_altopod is the Site ID and SiteAvailSecs is the site availability in secs:

```
level_altopod | datestr    | timestr  | SiteAvailSecs
```

The availability report is coming every 15mins (900 Secs), below are the data for the hour between 12:00 and 13:00 :

```
|           124 | 2021-08-30 | 12:45:00 |           900 |
|           121 | 2021-08-30 | 12:45:00 |           900 |
|           122 | 2021-08-30 | 12:45:00 |           900 |
|           120 | 2021-08-30 | 12:45:00 |           900 |
|           124 | 2021-08-30 | 12:30:00 |           900 |
|           120 | 2021-08-30 | 12:30:00 |           900 |
|           122 | 2021-08-30 | 12:30:00 |           900 |
|           121 | 2021-08-30 | 12:30:00 |           900 |
|           121 | 2021-08-30 | 12:15:00 |           900 |
|           120 | 2021-08-30 | 12:15:00 |           900 |
|           124 | 2021-08-30 | 12:15:00 |           900 |
|           122 | 2021-08-30 | 12:15:00 |           900 |
|           124 | 2021-08-30 | 12:00:00 |           900 |
|           122 | 2021-08-30 | 12:00:00 |           900 |
|           121 | 2021-08-30 | 12:00:00 |           900 |
|           120 | 2021-08-30 | 12:00:00 |           900 |
```

As you can see there is 4 entries for each ID (Start time 12:00, 12:15, 12:30 and 12:45)
i want to select and sum the 4 entries of each ID to have an output like the following :

```
|           ID  | Date       | Time     | Site Avail    |    
|           124 | 2021-08-30 | 12:00:00 |          3600 |
|           121 | 2021-08-30 | 12:00:00 |          3600 |
|           122 | 2021-08-30 | 12:00:00 |          3600 |
|           120 | 2021-08-30 | 12:00:00 |          3600 |
```

I tried the following but it gives the sum for all the IDs as shown below :

```
SELECT level_altopod, datestr, timestr, SiteAvailSecs
FROM amg_hourly_bts_sensor
where datestr="20210830" and hour(timestr) ="12"
group by "level_altopod";
```

```
| level_altopod | datestr    | timestr  | SiteAvailSecs |
+---------------+------------+----------+---------------+
|           124 | 2021-08-30 | 12:45:00 |           900 |
```

Comment: Based on the syntax of the SQL, I removed the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Use SUM(SiteAvailSecs) instead of SiteAvailSecs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT level_altopod, datestr, MIN(timestr), SUM(SiteAvailSecs)
FROM amg_hourly_bts_sensor
WHERE datestr = '20210830' and hour(timestr) = 12
GROUP BY level_altopod, datestr;
```

You have multiple problems with your code:

- Your `SELECT` columns are inconsistent with the `GROUP BY` columns.
- You are comparing integers to strings.
- You are aggregating by a string (the actual problem).
- You are not summing anything.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, it works. I also noticed that it works with my command when I remove the "" from group by "level_altopod".